# 501 Not Implemented on devices/tenant endpoint

Tags: eclipse-hono

I'm running Hono v1.4.0, but get 501 Not Implemented when calling the devices endpoint with:

http://{{REGISTRY_IP}}:{{REGISTRY_PORT_HTTP}}/v1/devices/{{TENANT}}?enabled=false

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `501 Not Implemented` response, I understood that you are using the file based device registry. In Hono 1.4.0, this search devices operation has been implemented only in the MongoDB based device registry and not in the file-based counterpart. This feature in the file based registry is planned for 1.5.0 release. I would suggest to use the MongoDB based device registry, where this feature already exists.

Answer (score 2):

The *search Devices* operation is implemented in the Mongo DB based registry only in 1.4.0. The implementation for the file based registry has been recently added to the master branch and will be available in 1.5.0.

Apart from that, the syntax for the query you are using is wrong. Please refer to the [Registry API documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/api/management/#/devices/searchDevicesForTenant) for the correct syntax of the *filterJson* query parameter. Note that you will need to properly URL encode the parameter value ...